# simple smack jabber program taking very long to connect on android

Tags: java, android, smack

Using [smack jabber library 4.3.1](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.3-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide), my android program takes 84 seconds to connect, which is fairly long. I [have seen a discussion in a forum](https://igniterealtime.jiveon.com/thread/59872) about a similar problem, but it affected earlier versions of SMACK.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is the smack the code am using to connect.

```
                XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration cc= XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .setCompressionEnabled(true)
                        .setUsernameAndPassword("smackuser","ilovesmack")
                        .setXmppDomain("xmpp.jp")
                        .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
                        .build();
                connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(cc);
                connection.addConnectionListener(MainActivity.this);
                connection.connect();
                connection.login();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply call once. For example in Application class

```
AndroidSmackInitializer.initialize(Context);
```

before any XMPP connections

[OLD ANSWER. DONT USE]
I found the problem. SMACK jabber uses [minidns](https://github.com/MiniDNS) and minidns [has a recently fixed bug on android 8](https://github.com/MiniDNS/minidns/issues/74). I solved the problem by using the code below. Thanks to @Flow

```
//////////////////////smack///////////////////////////////////////
implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.3.1"
implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.3.1"
implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.3.1"
implementation 'de.measite.minidns:minidns-hla:0.2.4'//added this
```

added minidns dependency

```
import org.minidns.dnsserverlookup.android21.AndroidUsingLinkProperties;
AndroidUsingLinkProperties.setup(context);//add this
cc=XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .setCompressionEnabled(true)
                        .setUsernameAndPassword(username,password)
                        .setXmppDomain(domain)
                        .build();
                xmpptcpConnection=new XMPPTCPConnection(cc);
                xmpptcpConnection.addConnectionListener(this);
                xmpptcpConnection.connect();
                xmpptcpConnection.login();
```